# How to run the mongodb $where operator in powershell

Tags: mongodb, powershell, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to write the following mongodb shell command in powershell:

```
db.tag.find({$where:"'star wars episode VII'.search(this.name) >= 0"})
```

So far what I have done is:

```
$tagCollection = $db["tag"]

$query = @{
    "name" = @{ '$where' = "'star wars episode VII'.search(this['name']) >= 0;" }
}

$cursor = $tagCollection.find([MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument]$query)
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], TargetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
```

Any idea/recommendation about what is wrong would be high appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

```
$tagCollection = $db["tag"]

$query = @{
    '$where' = "'star wars episode VII'.search(this['name']) >= 0;"
}

$cursor = $tagCollection.find([MongoDB.Driver.QueryDocument]$query)
```